# IPN callback for recurring payment not received

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I getting this IPN notify from Paypal when I create recurring profile:

`{"payment_cycle":"Daily","txn_type":"recurring_payment_profile_created","last_name":"buyer","initial_payment_status":"Completed","next_payment_date":"03:00:00 Aug 12, 2015 PDT", ...`

According to next_payment_date, I should get another payment notify in last few hours, but not.

Have I miss something? or need manual to accept payment?

Note: I do in Sandbox.

Comment: Have you double checked your IPN history in your PayPal account to see if it is or isn't being sent out?  If it is, it will also show if your system is is replying back with a 200ok when it's sent or what error is being sent.

Comment: Thanks, it work now. It just maybe it slow in sandbox.